# Real Time Javascript Calculation Based On Form Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

I'm trying to make a real-time calculator based on form inputs, when I use a sample div it works but I seem to be missing something when I try to print the total inside an input...

**Working Markup Solution:**

```
 <input id='first' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="bus_ticket"  placeholder="Bus Ticket..." required/><br />

<input id='second' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="plane_ticket"  placeholder="Plane Ticket..." required/><br />

<input id='third' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="hotel_expenses"  placeholder="Hotel Expenses..." required/><br />

 <input id='fourth' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="eating_expenses"  placeholder="Eating Expenses..." required/><br />

Total : <span id="total_expenses"></span>
```

**Working Script**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes


    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
    var fourthValue = parseFloat($('#fourth').val());

    $('#total_expenses').html(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue + fourthValue); // add them and output it
});
```

**Non-Working Markup**

```
<input id='total_expenses' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="funding"  placeholder="Total Expenses..."/>
```

**Non-Working Script**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
    var fourthValue = parseFloat($('#fourth').val());
    document.getElementById('#total_expenses').value(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue + fourthValue);
// add them and output it
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**## Here's a working JSFiddle.**

You've been confusing Javascript and jQuery codes.

```
// Wrong code:
document.getElementById('#total_expenses').value(sum)
//Correct code:
document.getElementById('total_expenses').value() = sum
```

Also, change `parseFloat` to `Number` so you don't get `NaN` when at least one of your input fields is blank.

**BONUS:** change your `<input type="text" />` to `<input type="number" />` to prevent "non-numerical" inputs.

Comment: Very neat. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Good neat and clean solution @ITWitch

Answer (score 1):

You can try this jquery code

```
var totalValue = firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue + fourthValue;
$('#total_expenses').val(totalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when using getElementById you can omit the #. Secondly, assigning a value to an input using vanilla JS is done by simple assignment, and not a function call. So that line should look like this:

```
document.getElementById('total_expenses').value = firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue + fourthValue;
```