# Live Form Field Calculations in Django Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am creating a stock market site and would like to show the total purchase value live as the user is typing rather than as an error during form clean. The calculation involves multiplying two fields. The first is a quantity field which is just a number the user inputs. The second is the stock which is a drop down for a foreign key. The user selects a stock and an attribute of the stock is the price. I would like to multiply these fields and display the result each time a user alters a field. I would also like to do this with a model form if possible.
I have tried using {{ form.field.value }} within the template to get one the fields but I cannot get it to update for a change. For the stock field, I think my best bet is to create a matching array in javascript and once I can get a live updating form value match it to the stock price from the array. Another possibility may be using getElementById with the field id but I have been unable to get that to work so far as well.

Here is an example not made by me that is close to what I want to do [Real Time Javascript Calculation Based On Form Inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730666/real-time-javascript-calculation-based-on-form-inputs)

Any help is much appreciated!

Models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    @property
    def price():
         do some calculations

class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_types = (
        ('buy', 'Buy'),
        ('sell', 'Sell'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=transaction_types)
    quantity = models.BigIntegerField()
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=30)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Forms.py

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = ['transaction_type', 'stock', 'quantity']
    widgets = {
        'quantity': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id': 'quant', 'name': 'quant'})
    }


   def clean(self):
        super(TransactionForm, self).clean()
        quantity = self.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
        stock= self.cleaned_data.get('stock')
        transaction_type = self.cleaned_data.get('transaction_type')
        purchase_price = stock.price
        if quantity < 1:
            self._errors['quantity'] = self.error_class(['You must purchase at least one share.'])
        elif quantity * purchase_price > self.user.profile.buying_power and transaction_type == 'buy':
            self._errors['quantity'] = self.error_class([
                f'Your purchase value (${round(quantity * purchase_price, 2)}) must be less than or equal to your buying power '
                f'(${round(self.user.profile.buying_power, 2)}). You can afford a maximum of '
                f'{floor(self.user.profile.buying_power / purchase_price)} share(s).'])
```

Trade.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <form method="POST" id="trade_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Trade</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>Quantity: <span id="quantity"></span></p>
    <script>
        $('input').keyup(function () { // run anytime the value changes
            let quant = Number($('#quant').val());
            $('#quantity').html(quant);
        });
    </script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Failed attempt

```
                <script>
                var stock_prices = new Array();
                {% for stock in stocks %}
                    stock_prices ["{{ stock .name }}"] = {{ stock .price }};
                {% endfor %}

                function getStockPrice() {
                    var price = 0;
                    var selectedStock = document.getElementById("id_stock");
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedStock.length; i++) {
                        if (selectedStock[i].checked) {
                            price = stock_prices [selectedStock[i].value];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return price;
                }

                function getQuantity() {
                    var quantity = document.getElementById("quant");
                    var howmany = 0;
                    howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
                    return howmany;
                }

                function getTotal() {
                    var total = getStockPrice() * getQuantity();

                    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML =
                        "Total Price: $" + total;

                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: what would you like code of?

Comment: What you've tried and not understood/didn't work/etc.

Comment: I added code. Everything works for the form models and stuff saves in the database exactly like I want. I just am trying to improve the user experience by doing the calculations live instead of having to wait for a submit and form error.

Comment: Ok so where is _that_ attempt?

Comment: the attempt is in the script tag at the bottom of the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Basically, I made an api using Django Rest Framework. From there, I used Vue to make my form a v-model. I used watch to call the api every time the v-model changed.

Comment: can you give more details on your solution?